# How To Show Interstitial Ads in The getView Function in Kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I'm a Beginner in Kotlin and I want a way to display Interstitial Ad every time I click on the button `tvName`, but on the contrary, the app crashes whenever I click on the button. I searched for the solution for a long time.

Here's MainActivity

```
import ...


@Suppress("UNREACHABLE_CODE")
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var mAdView : AdView
    var adapter:ChaptersAdapter?=null
    var listOfChapters= ArrayList<Chapters>()

    @SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        MobileAds.initialize(this) {}
        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView)
        val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest)


        loadChapters()
        adapter = ChaptersAdapter(listOfChapters, this)
        lvchapters.adapter = adapter


        MobileAds.initialize(this,
            "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713")

        mInterstitialAd = InterstitialAd(this)
        mInterstitialAd.adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712"
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())




    }


    fun loadChapters(){

        listOfChapters.add(Chapters(" Chapter 1 ", applicationContext.assets.open("Chapter0.txt").bufferedReader().use {
            it.readText()
        }
        ))

        listOfChapters.add(Chapters(" Chapter 2 ", applicationContext.assets.open("Chapter1.txt").bufferedReader().use {
            it.readText()
        }
        ))


    }


    class ChaptersAdapter: BaseAdapter {
        var context:Context?=null
        var listOfChaptersLocal= ArrayList<Chapters>()
        constructor(listOfChapters:ArrayList<Chapters>,context:Context){
            listOfChaptersLocal=listOfChapters
            this.context=context

        }





        override fun getView(p0: Int, p1: View?, p2: ViewGroup?): View {
            val chapters= listOfChaptersLocal[p0]
            var inflator= context!!.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
            val chaptersView=inflator.inflate(R.layout.list_chapters,null)
            chaptersView.tvName.text= chapters.name!!
            chaptersView.**tvName.setOnClickListener** {
                // **i want to show the Ads in this time frame** but like this example it didn't work
                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded) {
                        mInterstitialAd.show()
                } else {
                       Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.")
                }
                val intent =Intent(context,ChapterDetails::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("name",chapters.name!!)
                intent.putExtra("des",chapters.des!!)
                context!!.startActivity(intent)

            }
            return chaptersView
        }



        override fun getItem(p0: Int): Any {
            return listOfChaptersLocal[p0]
        }

        override fun getItemId(p0: Int): Long {
            return p0.toLong()
        }

        override fun getCount(): Int {
            return listOfChaptersLocal.size
        }
    }

}
```